# How do I call a function in main.cpp from a library I made?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, visual-c++

So I made a small library (unfinished) for my game engine. In main I include the library
In the library I have an "Engine" class, which keeps info about the window, OS, settings etc. In that class I want to have a while(true) in which I call an "update(delta)" in main.cpp
Is that possible?

This is the class:

```
class Engine {
    Time delta;
    bool run = true;
public:
    Engine(std::function<bool(float)> _update) {
        while (run) {
            run = _update(delta.get_call_time());
        }
    }
};
```

This is what I call in main:

```
Engine engine(_update);
```

Comment: We'll need more information about what you're doing because the direct answer to what you are asking is "The same way you call any other method."

Comment: It doesn't work just by calling that function, because I don't #include main in Engine, just Engine in main. How do I post a file?

Comment: That looks completely backwards. Normally, `main` would create such an object and call its update function in a loop, passing the information it needs.

Comment: I edited the question so the code inside look like valid C++

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, but I think the most popular one is to use a callback using `std::function`:

```
class Engine {
    Delta delta = clock();

public:
    Engine(Vector2 window_size, std::function<void(Delta)> update) {
        update(delta)
    }
};
```

Comment: it gives me "namespace has no member function"

Comment: @TudorSzabo you have to include the correct standard header. Please follow the [`std::function` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: @TudorSzabo hint: this is the `functional` header.

Comment: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ).

class Engine {
 Time delta;
 bool run = true;
public:
 Engine(std::function<bool(float)> _update, Vector2 window_size) {
  while (run) {
   run = _update(delta.get_call_time());
  }
 }
};

Comment: @TudorSzabo you have problem elsewhere in your code. Post a different question for that problem.

Comment: I don't even know where the problem is, or where to start looking for it...
I edited the question it has the relevant code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229114/discussion-between-tudor-szabo-and-guillaume-racicot).